# How to format a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a CSV file in python that looks something like this:

```
Person A    Class 1
            Class 2
            Class 3
Person B    Class 1
            Class 2
            Class 3
            Class 4
Person C    Class 1
Person D    Class 1
            Class 2
```

I have a dictionary where dict[person A] = [class 1, class 2, class 3], but it's easy to mess around with the data structure. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tired? Which is your problem with what you have tried?

Comment: You don't want that format, you want variable length records `"A,1,2,3\nB,1,2,3,4\nC,1\nD,1,2"` (`"\n"` is a newline character),

Comment: Take a look at the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you would use a CSV file. The correct way to structure your data would be to have a header

```
Person,Class
```

and under that rows in the form

```
A,1
A,2
A,3
B,1
B,2
B,3
B,4
C,1
D,1
D,2
```

You would simply need to iterate through your dict and within each person's entry, iterate through their classes and do something loke `csvfile.writerow([person, class])` for each pair.

Comment: I'd rather suggest a variable length record format (`"A,1,2,3"`), but I appreciate your effort to drive the OP into better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Getting exactly the format you are showing you can do by:

```
data = dict()

data['Person A'] = ['Class 1', 'Class 2', 'Class 3']
data['Person B'] = ['Class 1', 'Class 2']

outstr = ''
for key, value in data.items():
    left = key
    for line in value:
        outstr += left + '\t' + line + '\n'
        left = ' '*len(key)

print(outstr)
```

But as gboffi has commented, if the csv format is not written in stone, you might have better luck using a variable length records format.